# d3 text elements not rendering inside circle

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add texts to svg circles.  I've read other posts about using the grouping "g" tag, and I've tried that, but my text still isn't rendering.  I see the text element exists in the console though.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 var node = svg
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(
      d3
        .drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended)
    );
  node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", (d) => {
      return d.type === "application" ? 50 : 20;
    })
    .attr("fill", (d) => {
      return d.type === "application" ? "red" : "blue";
    });

  node
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  force.on("tick", function () {
    link
      .attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });
    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
```

**Added correct code based on accepted answer.**

Why is this still not rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can solve this is to bind your data to the group elements first and then append circles and text individually. So your code becomes:

```
var node = svg
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes");

node
  .append("circle")
// all circle-related code

node
  .append("text")
// all text related code, including x and y
```

Only two (AFAIK) `svg` elements allow other elements to be nested within them: `g` and `text`. When you call `append` on the selection of `circles`, you're appending a `text` element as a child of `circle` - which it doesn't support.

Comment: How would I use "cx" and "cy" of each circle element to center the text elements?

Comment: I tried just setting x and y to 100, and still nothing rendered.

Comment: Okay, so that looks better in the console, but the circles are rendering in the 0,0 position. How do I get the circles positions correct? `node` is returning a `cy` and `cy` field, but it's not rendering in the center. I've edited the code above.

Comment: But even the circles are in the top corner now. Before I made the changes they were positioned properly. And how would I know what x and y are when it's based on where the circles are dragged?

Comment: Depends on how you wrote the drag functions. Generally, the pattern is to use transform translate on the `g` so that the circle and the text move together from their initial position. Not sure why circles are in the top corner. When you inspect the circle elements, are `cx` and `cy` values correct?

Comment: yes, they are reflecting the correct positions. Even if I drag the circles from the top corner, the positions update, but the circles don't move

Comment: Could be related to the simulation. If you post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a complete example, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Okay, I made a version on fiddle with a small subset of the data: https://jsfiddle.net/rbb791/q6Ljwxb0/

Comment: When you call `.attr("cx", d => d.cx`), `d` is a row in your data and your data doesn't have a cx column so `cx` attribute (and `cy`) is null and your circles are all in the top left corner.

Comment: But before I made the change, `cx`, `cy` was determined by the force and I didn't have to specify their location. How do I go back to that with this new grouping of circles and texts?

Comment: Hm..best ask a new question since it's more about simulation code rather than text not rendering when appending it to a circle.